# Store QGIS annotations in PostgreSQL/PostGIS database

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a multiuser QGIS project stored on PostGIS database.

Is it possible to store annotations in a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database so that every user can add annotations directly on the map?